# Iterate all properties of an aggregate class and instantiate?

Tags: c#

There's all kinds of really awesome info on how to iterate through all of the properties of a class. What I want to do, however, is iterate through them and instantiate each property as new in the constructor... The class is an aggregate class representing a collection of entity framework model objects/classes. I could instantiate each in turn but that is going to be huge and a problem for maintenance when I decide to add another table to the database...

```
public class ClsAggModel {
    public ClsAggModel() {
        foreach (PropertyInfo props in this.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            props.SetValue = new props.GetType(); //problem here!
        }
    }

   public clsItem1 pProp1{ get; set; }
   public clsItem2 pProp2{ get; set; }
   //...and so on
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn't seem to know what `props` is at this point:

> The type or namespace name 'props' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

which seems kind of strange since I just i stantiated it in the loop signature. I could fill out each property and do the private variable and all that jazz but what good is reflection if you can't abuse it?

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to call a default created type use the activator like this

```
props.SetValue(this, Activator.CreateInstance(props.GetType()));
```

Note, **this will still fail if there is no default constructor**. Because you are using reflection your compiler can no longer check for this.

Note 2: Be vary carefully with abusing reflection. it's a sure way to shoot yourself in the foot sooner or later.

**Update** of course setvalue is a method, changed this

Comment: Hrm, SetValue is a method therefore `.SetValue(Activator...)` but it requires a second parameter so I'm still stuck with the same problem and passing in `null` for kicks and giggles gets me `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Comment: `props.SetValue = ...` should be `props.SetValue(this, Activator.CreateInstance(props.GetType())`

Comment: You should add a default empty constructor to every class you want to create a class for.

Comment: a default controctor or make sure to have no constructor at all, and a default will be created

Answer (score 0):

You can not create instance on base of `.GetType()` in this manner.

This will not work:

```
new props.GetType();
```

You should try using:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(props.GetType());
```

Comment: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` It needs a second parameter: a value

Answer (score 0):

Based on already provided solutions your code should look like this:

```
public class ClsAggModel {
    public ClsAggModel() {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            var newValue = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.GetType());
            prop.SetValue(this, newValue);
        }
    }

   public clsItem1 pProp1{ get; set; }
   public clsItem2 pProp2{ get; set; }
```

Keep in mind that all properties types must allow dynamic creation, by providing a default constructor (it is automatically there, if other constructor is not defined).

Comment: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` on `Activator.CreateInstance` These are model-first EF classes inside `ClsAggModel`. I could extend each class as partial and deal with the constructor but that kind of defeats the purpose of iterating.

Comment: Can you please provide us the type of the property that throws this error? Iterating through "all" properties might get you some undesired properties. From what I know, model first entities should have only the default constructor if class is not extended.

Comment: It's an aggregate class where each property is an Entity Framework model. For example, `pAccount` is going to be a property that contains a model-first Entity Framework class `account` for the account table. That object itself is, as model-first EF objects tend to be, is a collection of properties of base types such as string, int, and so forth. When in debug, watch window name of `prop.GetType()` returns `prop.GetType() {Name = "RuntimePropertyInfo" FullName = "System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}` This is, incidentally, not some "unexpected" property.

Comment: I want to know prop.PropertyType and prop.Name (not properties from PropertyInfo type) when it throws the exception.

Comment: PropertyType is `prop.PropertyType {Name = "account" FullName = "WCF_Tracker_Library.account"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}`

Name is: "pAccount". Like I said, an entity framework object because the class whose properties I'm iterating is an aggregate class of EF objects.

Comment: Does it have a constructor defined? I thought models had a parameterless constructor. An alternative is to customize generation (.tt) templates to generate one, if one with parameters is already there.